# Comment « toutefois » glisse-t-il sémantiquement pour signifier « en revanche, l'heurt, le différend » ?

Tags: étymologie, francais-ancien

Veuillez déceler  les mots que j'ai colorié en gras dans la  [définition de TOUTEFOIS](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/toutefois) citée :

> Adverbe coordonnant, introduit un rectificatif destiné à empêcher qu'on ne généralise trop la portée de l'assertion précédente ou à la `limiter` en énonçant un fait qui en est exclu: *toutefois* pose deux faits qui `s'opposent` sans que le deuxième ait le pouvoir de détruire la valeur du premier`` (M.-A. Morel, *Ét. sur les moyens gramm. et lex. propres à exprimer une concess. en fr. contemp.*, 1980, p. 736).
>
> **A. −** [Dans une phrase grammaticalement indép., marque `une relation d'oppos.` restrictive avec la phrase ou la prop. précédente; ce qu'exprime la première prop. n'est pas une raison suffisante pour que ce qu'exprime la seconde soit exclu]
>
> [...]
>
> **Rem.** Contrairement à *cependant* ou *pourtant* qui ont un sens concess., *toutefois* signifie plutôt la `restriction`. Ainsi on dira: *Sa voiture est en rodage; cependant/pourtant il ne la ménage pas* (« bien qu'elle soit en rodage... »). On accepte plus difficilement: *Sa voiture est en rodage; toutefois il ne la ménage pas*; la prop. _il ne la ménage pa_s ne limitant pas la validité de la prop. qui précède − que cette prop. soit considérée en elle-même ou dans ses conséquences −, *toutefois* n'y a pas sa place.
>
> **B. −** [Marque une oppos. entre deux mots, syntagmes ou prop., de même fonction gramm.]
>
> [...]
>
> **Étymol. et Hist. A.** Loc. conj. **1.** *ca* 1180 *totes les foiz que* « chaque fois que » (Chrétien de Troyes, *Yvain*, éd. M. Roques, 2585); *ca* 1208 [ms. 2emoit. xives.] *totes foiz que* « chaque fois que » (Villehardouin, *Conquête de Constantinople*, 166) *cf.* Imbs, *Prop.*, pp. 260-265.
>
> **2.** *ca* 1230 *toutes les fois que* « aussitôt que » (*Chevaliers as 2 espees*, 2440 ds T.-L.). [TOUTEFOIS : Définition de TOUTEFOIS](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/toutefois)
>
> **2.** *ca* 1230 *toutes les fois que* « aussitôt que » (*Chevaliers as 2 espees*, 2440 ds T.-L.).
>
> **B.** Adv. 1284 [ms. F] « pourtant, `en revanche` »

[Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/toutefois) ne repère pas les notions sémantiques qui sous-tendent  'toutefois' et  l'opposition et la restriction. Il m'est évident que 'revanche' signifie la rétorsion, qui entraîne un différend.   Mais 'toutefois' me paraît neutre, et n'entraîne aucun heurt.

Comment: Je ne trouve nulle part que « toutefois » signifie « en revanche » et n'ai jamais compris « toutefois » ainsi ; il est vrai cependant que dans l'ancien français cette acception existait : (TLFi, étymol.) B. Adv. 1284 [ms. F] « pourtant, en revanche » (BRUNET LATIN, Trésor, éd. P. Chabaille, I, 176, p. 224: ja soit lïons de si haut corage [...], toutefoiz aime il home mervilleusement [éd. Fr. J. Carmody: totesvoies]) _ Quel est le dictionnaire moderne qui donne cette définition ?

Comment: entrainer : (TLFi)  Amener, faire venir à la suite. _ Il me semble que le différend est la cause et donc une réalité qui précède (il ne vient pas à la suite), à moins que je ne comprenne pas ce qui est vraiment dit ici.

Comment: @LPH 'Quel est le dictionnaire moderne qui donne cette définition ?' Je me focalisais sur cette définition-là que vous avez citée. Je n'ai pas perçu qu'elle ne s'applique qu'au ancien français !

Comment: Tu ne dis pas dans ta question où tu as lu que *toutefois* puisse vouloir dire *en revanche*. Aucun des dictionnaires contemporains que j'ai consultés (DHLF, Larousse, Petit Robert) ou en ligne ne signale que *toutefois* puisse avoir le sens de *en revanche*.

Comment: L'indication de l'emploi « pourtant, en revanche » dans une traduction du *Trèsor* de Brunetto Latini (13e s.) que LPH signale dans la partie étymologique du TLF, résulte  probablement d'une erreur du traducteur (édition jugée parfois peu sûre).  Ce que confirme cet article [Les « pseudo-adverbes » concessifs neporuec, neporquant, nequedent et l’adverbe toute(s)voie(s) en ancien français](https://www.cairn.info/revue-syntaxe-et-semantique-2007-1-page-107.html?contenu=article) qui cite la même phrase avec sa traduction.

Comment: Si *revanche* implique un différend, l'expression *en revanche* est beaucoup plus neutre et n'implique pas nécessairement un différend.

Comment: « En revanche » n'apparait qu'une fois dans une **mauvaise** traduction Trèsor de Brunetto Latini (13e s.) qui résulte probablement d'une erreur du traducteur (édition Chabaille jugée  peu sûre, voir ce [compte rendu de lecture](https://www.persee.fr/doc/roma_0035-8029_1950_num_71_281_3698_t1_0126_0000_2)).  Voir [ici](https://www.cairn.info/revue-syntaxe-et-semantique-2007-1-page-107.html?contenu=article) une meilleure traduction de la même phrase.

Comment: Les sens sont proches; *toutefois* serait plutôt synonyme de *malgré tout*, apportant une nuance à ce qui précède, tandis que *en revanche* signale une opposition nette.

Comment: @Laure Probablement que c'est extrapolé de [ceci](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mais#Synonymes) ; l'entrée pour _toutefois_ etc. sur Wiktionnaire contient un lien vers cette section... probablement qu'on aurait dû utiliser un autre terme que synonyme pour relier ces adverbes...

Comment: Peut-être faudrait se rapprocher du terme 'ma foi', ce qui au pluriel donnerait 'toutes les fois'. Dans ce cas donné, 'il se pourrait qu'il pleuve demain, ma foi, je ne pourrais le dire...' conviendrait au terme donné...

Answer (score 3):

Contrairement à ce que suggère le titre de la question, *toutefois* n'a pas "*glissé sémantiquement*". Il a toujours eu une valeur **concessive** même si, effectivement, l'expression dont *toutefois* est issu n'en portait pas.

*Toutefois* est ce que certains appellent un *marqueur de concession*.
Le français moderne en connait d'autres (*cependant, pourtant, néanmoins*...) (0)

Ces adverbes proviennent de locutions qui n'étaient pas des marqueurs de discours et qui, effectivement, ne portaient pas de valeur concessive.

Pour ce qui est de *toutefois*, le point de départ est la locution nominale ***to(u)tes voies*** dont le sens est celui de *par tous les chemins*, *de toutes les manières, dans tous les cas*)

Comme les trois autres, cette locution a d'abord subi un processus de grammaticalisation qui l'a transformée en forme adverbiale figée, (toujours sans valeur concessive)

Cette forme adverbiale a, par suite, connu un processus de pragmaticalisation (4) au cours de laquelle elle acquiert une valeur concessive qui, dans un premier temps coexistera avec la valeur d'origine (non concessive) avant de devenir sa seule valeur. (1)

Comme en chaque occasion où *voie* perd sa valeur spatiale au profit d'une valeur temporelle, il se transforme en *fois*.
C'est à partir de 1350 que l'on ne rencontrera plus que la forme "moderne" de *toutefois* (parfois écrite *toutefoys*) ayant dans le même temps que la perte de sa valeur spatiale acquis la valeur concessive.

Pour les raisons ayant amené la valeur concessive :
- on commencera par observer la présence de ***tout*** qui influence de façon similaire les marqueurs de concession dans de nombreuses langues. (2)
- On observera aussi la position de l'adverbe dans les premiers textes.
Le fait que *toutevoie* / *toutefois* se trouvent très souvent en début de proposition principale après une subordonnée concessive a pu s’interpréter comme la preuve qu’ils étaient eux-mêmes concessifs.(3)

Enfin, et comme plusieurs fois observé dans les commentaires de l'OP, *"en revanche"* n'a pas grand chose à faire dans cette discussion. *En revanche* étant tenu non pour un concessif mais bien pour un **adversatif**.

---

<sup>(0) Le français-ancien connaissait *nemporro, neporuec, neporquant,nonporcant,nequedent,neportant, nonportant...*</sup>

<sup>(1) Soutet date de la fin du XIII<sup>è</sup> l'apparition de la valeur concessive : "*Moult en y ot de noiez en l' un fleuve et en l' autre ; et **toute voies** en 
demoura il grant partie aus quiex en n’osa assembler* (Joinville, Vie de saint Louis)</sup>

<sup>(2) On peut penser à l'anglais (*although*, *however*, *anyway*...); à l'allemand (*allerdings* *bei all*...); sans compter le latin *quamquam*</sup>

<sup>(3) C'est en tout cas le constat de Martin et Wilmet (1980 : 232), entre autres.</sup>

<sup>(4) Entendre ici le développement, par une unité lexicale ou grammaticale, d’un emploi stabilisé où elle ne participe plus à la construction d’un sens référentiel, mais marque une **prise de position métadiscursive du locuteur** (5) (cf. Dostie 2004)</sup>
<sup>Pour une compréhension plus détaillée du processus de pragmaticalisation, on consultera [Badiou/Buchy (p127-)](https://halshs.archives-ouvertes.fr/halshs-00727283/document) et en particulier le synoptique p138.</sup>

<sup>(5) La prise de position métadiscursive du locuteur est un fait commun à tous les marqueurs discursifs dans la mesure où (cf Morel 1996) la concession consiste à poser une relation A->B avec B, inverse d'un B1 attendu subjectivement (dans la logique du locuteur) comme phénomène relié à A.</sup>

Comment: 'Cette forme adverbiale a, par suite, connu un processus de pragmaticalisation au cours de laquelle elle acquiert une valeur concessive qui, dans un premier temps coexistera avec la valeur d'origine (non concessive) avant de devenir sa seule valeur.' SVP, pourriez-vous élargir ?

Comment: Can you please respond in, by editing, your answer? Comment chains are
cumbersome to read.