# Comment « pourtant » glisse-t-il sémantiquement pour signifier « l'heurt, le différend » ?

Tags: étymologie, francais-ancien

[pourtant - Dictionnaire de français Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/pourtant/63149?q=pourtant#62440)

> [1.] Marque **l'opposition** entre deux phrases ou deux mots : Il n'a pas compris ce qu'on lui disait, pourtant il est intelligent.
>
> [2.]   Insiste sur **une constatation** qui s'oppose au contexte : Je te l'avais pourtant dit.

[Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pourtant) ne repère pas les notions sémantiques qui sous-tendent 'l'opposition, une constatation' et 'pourtant'.   Mais 'pourtant' me paraît neutre, et n'entraîne ni contestation ni opposition.

> #### Étymologie
>
> [Lexicalisation](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/lexicalisation) de *[pour](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pour) [tant](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tant)*, du latin *[pro](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pro) [tanto](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tanto)*.

Comment: Qu'est-ce qui te fait dire qu'il y aurait eu un glissement sémantique de pourtant à en revanche, car ces deux mots n'ont pas le même sens.

Comment: @Laure C'est plus clair maintenant ?

Comment: On pourrait poser la question aussi pour "cependant" qui historiquement signifiait "pendant ce temps".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note :** La réponse à cette question comporterait les mêmes observations générales faites [ici à propos de *toutefois*](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/37921/comment-toutefois-glisse-t-il-s%C3%A9mantiquement-pour-signifier-en-revanche-l). On s'y reportera au besoin.

Pour ce qui est du cas particulier de *pourtant* :

Pourtant est issu de *por tant* compris comme *à cause de ce fait que*, à valeur exclusivement **causale** donc.
Les opinions divergent sur la première occurrence de sa valeur concessive. Soulet retient le milieu du XII<sup>è</sup>. Elle attendra en tout cas le XVI<sup>è</sup> avant de devenir régulière.

Selon certains (Ménard, Buridant...) la valeur concessive est portée dès l'ancien français dans les phrases négatives :

*"Se tu es riches et mananz, **ne** soies orgueilleus **por tant**."*

*ne [à cause de ce fait que]* pouvant effectivement se comprendre comme *malgré cela*.

Ce **por tant** en phrase négative va d'ailleurs dès le XII<sup>è</sup> donner lieu à l'apparition d'un authentique connecteur concessif : *neportant* / *nonpourtant*.
Connecteur qui ne survivra pas au XVI<sup>è</sup> siècle.

---

NDaCOSwt : Un commentaire suggère un glissement sémantique de *por tant*.

***Pour autant*** qu'on puisse couper les cheveux en quatre, je laisserai volontiers les spécialistes du français-ancien argumenter.
Pour ma part, je lis *por tant* **au sens causal** dans la *Séquence de Sainte-Eulalie* c'est à dire un des tout premiers textes français.
J'en conclus donc facilement que *por tant* n'a pas glissé sémantiquement.
Après... peut-être le *por tanto* latin dont il est issu a-t-il lui glissé... mais cela... c'est : Une autre histoire.

Oui! Il est vrai qu'on rencontrera par la suite *por tant* parfois en concurrence avec un sens quantitatif.
Ce sens vivra sa vie en toute indépendance de *pourtant*, porté qu'il sera par la locution *pour autant*.

Comment: Comment 'por tant' a-t-il glissé sémantiquement pour signifier 'à cause de ce fait que' ?

Comment: @aCOSwt je comprends pas la ligne qui commence par `NDaCOSwt : Un commentaire` je vois ton pseudo, mais ça me rend la phrase un peu improbable, un peu comme si tu te répondais à toi même. Je pense que je doit manquer un détail... Ca veut dire autre chose qu'une référénce à ton pseudo ?

Comment: Ahh, je viens de comprendre, c'est comme NDR, NDLA, NDLR je suppose. Ca m'a vraiment perturbé la lecture. C'est d'un usage si courant ?

Comment: @StephaneRolland : Tu as bien compris. C'est un usage que je prends dans tous les travaux collaboratifs (dans lesquels je ne suis donc pas plus R que LA que LR) pour annoncer un nota représentant une opinion qui m'est personnelle.